# Manipulating xml file with sed

Tags: android, linux, bash, sed

I have my Strings.xml file containing the following code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<string name="hello">myurl</string>
<string name="app_name">MyApp</string>
</resources>
```

I want to manipulate the value of myurl using command line to a given URL by the user.

The command i'm using is

```
sed s/myurl/http://192.168.1.1:8080/ strings.xml
```

But it is throwing an error : sed: 1: "s/myurl/http://192.168. ...": bad flag in substitute command: '/'

This is caused by the two slashes (//). Any way to pass the value to the sed command ?

Comment: You should use a proper XML parsing utility such as `xmlstarlet` or a module in Python or Perl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use other delimiters with sed, like `!`:

```
sed 's!myurl!http://192.168.1.1:8080/!' strings.xml
```

The (ugly) alternative is to escape them:

```
sed 's/myurl/http:\/\/192.168.1.1:8080\//' strings.xml
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked! The second one. Ugly Alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Use `\` before all escape symbols.